# WCF Event Declaration

Tags: wcf

I see that WCF doesn't directly use events and instead uses OneWay delegate calls, but can someone show me a simple example on how to do this?

Here is what I have setup right now:

```
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnGetMapStoryboardsComplete(object sender, List<Storyboard> results);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your callback contract interface is called `IMyServiceCallback`, your service would execute the following code when it wanted to raise the event:

```
IMyServiceCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyServiceCallback>();
callback.OnGetMapStoryboardsComplete(...);
```

I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx) very helpful. It describes a transient event system and a persisted event system, either of which should satisfy any and all event scenarios, IMO.

HTH

To set up the callback contract:

```
interface IMyServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OnGetMapStoryboardsComplete(object sender, List<Storyboard>);
}
```

Then you need to indicate on your service contract that it is using this callback:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMyServiceCallback))]
interface IMyService
{
    // ...
}
```

Once you have done that and implemented your service, create a reference to the service.  The client will then have to include a class that implements `IMyServiceCallback`:

```
class EventHandler : IMyServiceCallback
{
    public void OnGetMapStoryBoardsComplete(object sender, List<Storyboard>)
    {
        // Do whatever needs to be done when the event is raised.
    }
}
```

When you connect from the client to the service you need to pass it an `InstanceContext` built with a reference to the object that will handle the events:

```
EventHandler eventHandler = new EventHandler();
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(new InstanceContext(eventHandler));
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: I dont think I have a callback contract, how do i set that up?

Comment: Does that answer your question, or are you still having issues?

Comment: MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(new InstanceContext(eventHandler)); <- I can't do this part because my client side does not know the implementation of the service, it just knows an IMyService interface, so I instantiate it with a ChannelFactory and an endpoint. How can I attach the event handler in that case?